# "deleted objects" container in active directory has been deleted

Tags: active-directory

My manager has inherited a lovely problem, Active Directory is very messed up here due to some inadvisable tampering.  Among the issues is that the "deleted objects" container in active directory has been deleted...but somehow it still exists.  He tries to create a new "deleted objects" container and he is blocked from doing so.  LDP.exe doesn't show the object.  We can't find it with queries, and the following from novell's site doesn't work either:

```
dsacls "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=Contoso,DC=com" /g CONTOSO\JaneDoe:LCRP
```

It shows that the closest match is exactly what he's searching for, but it's telling him he has insufficient rights.

This is a conundrum.  He says that if he is able to delete that object fully then Active Directory will re-create it and that problem will be solved.  Does anyone have some thoughts on this?

Thanks,

Nate

Comment: How do you know that it has been deleted? This isn't visible by default and shouldn't be. As I recall, to actually grant permissions to it, you first have to take ownership before that dsacls call would work.

Comment: He found command that showed that the object has an "isDeleted" property that is set to "True".  Further insight: this is a domain that was the 2000 version and has been upgraded several times.  It may be that in prior versions it was possible to soft-delete the object and after upgrade it has been locked down.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Active Directory is hosed up and doing all kinds of weird stuff.  We will probably have to migrate to a fresh domain that hasn't been tampered with over the course of a decade-plus, but this is one thing we can point to that is abnormal and may be a source of some of our woes.

Comment: OK but to help you here I need some sort of actionable problem statement. The original behavior in the top post actually sounds like it's doing what it's supposed to which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, the deleted objects container should not be set to isDeleted = True.  It should be viewable using LDP.exe and it is not.  We are trying to change the "is deleted" property to null or delete the object completely so that active directory will rebuild the container, but nothing is working.  We can't interface with it or manipulate it in any way.